# Microsoft Access View Button in Ribbon Disabled

Tags: ms-access

The view button in the ribbon is permanently disabled. I can get to the design view of an object by right clicking, but how did the ribbon button become disabled.

I have checked Trust Center settings, nothing seems different. It applies to all database new and old and has affected all 3 of my PCs.

What on earth is happening?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, that is normal. Double click or right click menu to open an object and VIew button is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Golly gee!

I been using Access since 97 days.

I had NOT noticed that if you click on an item in the nav pane, then the view/design button on the ribbon DOES NOT "enable".

Now, even in Access 2003 days?

I always used to ctrl-enter after selecting the object, and thus I never skipped a beat.

However, since 2007 (since the ribbon), it looks like for the last WHOPPING 16 years I NEVER noticed this behavior.

And I been hanging around on Access forms for the last 20 years, and AGAIN no one has pointed this out.

So, this has been the default behavior in Access for a VERY long time - at least 16 years!!!!

I tend to use the cursor keys anyway, and thus say to open a form “hotel” in design mode, then I do this:

[image]

So, in above, I type in hotels, and then use the down arrow key, pick off the one I want, and then use ctrl-enter key. And I done that since a97 and a2000 days.

However, quite interesting that you are correct! - Selecting an item in the nav pane does not "enable" the view/design option.

***Looks like it never did.***

However, since you already had to select/pick an item in the nav pane, then at that point a simple enter key tap opens the object, or as above shows, my long-time use of ctrl-enter key opens the object in design mode.

What the above means?

Not only did I never use that ribbon option in all these years, but I never even noticed that the design option does not even enable when selecting an option in the nav page (and it looks like few if not most have not noticed or pointed out this behavior in the last 16 years).

However, if you are from previous (pre-ribbon) days, when a2007/2010 came out, I had some frustration, and thus wrote this "survival" guide from a long-time developer’s point of view, and the result is I rather like the nav pane now, and if used correctly, you find it better then the older non ribbon UI in most cases.

Article:

***Become friends with the nav pane in 2010***

http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/navpne/NavTips.html

Answer (score 0):

That button only counts for opened objects.

If you double-click a table, it will display the records - and now the View button is enabled.

Same goes for other objects.

Comment: I've been using Access for nearly 30 years. That button has always been enabled as soon as you select (not open) an object. Even yesterday morning I used it. Something has changed. It is not normal behavior.

Comment: You may be right. I've sent a query about this to Microsoft.

Comment: I've got the response, that the behaviour you see, has been present since at least version 2010. In Access 2003 and back, however, the button was enabled.

Comment: From what I can tell, for the last 16 years (a long time), since the Ribbon, Access did not and does not enable the ribbon view/design button when selecting an item from the nav pane, and it looks like since ribbon days, it never did!